# Postfix long dns queries

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, performance

I use my postfix server as a relay to another provider. I dig a little to find out why sending a simple mail takes so much time. I figure out that postfix do complete DNS queries for each single mail (30 seconds lost) :

```
Apr 30 11:26:50 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: connecting to in.mailjet.com port 25
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: in.mailjet.com (MX): OK
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:26:55 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: lookup smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com type A flags 0
Apr 30 11:27:00 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com (A): OK
Apr 30 11:27:00 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:00 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:00 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: lookup smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com type A flags 0
Apr 30 11:27:05 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com (A): OK
Apr 30 11:27:05 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:05 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:05 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: lookup smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com type A flags 0
Apr 30 11:27:10 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com (A): OK
Apr 30 11:27:10 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:10 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:10 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: lookup smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com type A flags 0
Apr 30 11:27:15 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com (A): OK
Apr 30 11:27:15 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:15 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:15 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: lookup smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com type A flags 0
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com (A): OK
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: begin in.mailjet.com address list
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com/5.196.43.135
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com/178.32.115.14
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com/46.105.54.204
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com/37.59.74.234
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com/5.196.43.129
Apr 30 11:27:20 dev1 postfix/smtp[20917]: end in.mailjet.com address list
```

- Why postfix does these requests for every single mail ?
- Is it a good idea to configure postfix to use the first MX available with A DNS entry ? (and how can I achieve that ?)
- Is there a way to tell postfix to cache all these DNS diggings for at least one week ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Your host does not seem to be caching dns lookups. It should be.
2. No
3. Your operating system (not postfix) should cache every DNS record lookup it needs. [NSCD](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) is one common tool to cache "hosts" queries.

Comment: NSCD link was broken :(

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I thought this feature is OS-based and embedded in every distribution. So I understand that I have to set up a specific DNS cache service for my debian server. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the value of parameter [smtp_host_lookup](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_host_lookup) is `dns`. Because of that, postfix will **always** try to resolve the MX record recipient domain to determine the next-hop destination. Postfix rely on libc resolver to do the lookup so the expected behaviour would depends on the library. For example, postfix will alwasy do lookup via NS server defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Based on your logs above, looks like you have problem in your NS server. It's abnormal case when the single DNS lookup would take up to 5 seconds to return the result. Here the same logs when postfix lookup MX record of `in.mailjet.com`. It finished the lookup only in 2 seconds.

```
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: in.mailjet.com (MX): OK
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: message repeated 4 times: [ dns_get_answer: type MX for in.mailjet.com]
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com type A flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com (A): OK
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com type AAAA flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com (AAAA): Host found but no data record of requested type
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com type A flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com (A): OK
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com type AAAA flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com (AAAA): Host found but no data record of requested type
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com type A flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com (A): OK
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com type AAAA flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com (AAAA): Host found but no data record of requested type
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com type A flags 0
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com (A): OK
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:37 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com type AAAA flags 0
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com (AAAA): Host found but no data record of requested type
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: smtp_addr_one: host smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com type A flags 0
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com (A): OK
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_get_answer: type A for smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: lookup smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com type AAAA flags 0
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: dns_query: smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com (AAAA): Host found but no data record of requested type
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: begin in.mailjet.com address list
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr9.mailjet.com/37.59.74.234
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr10.mailjet.com/5.196.43.129
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr11.mailjet.com/5.196.43.135
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr7.mailjet.com/178.32.115.14
May  1 00:20:38 dewa postfix/smtp[4002]: pref   10 host smtp-ovhfr8.mailjet.com/46.105.54.204
```

So, your best bet to solve the problem from the root is find out why your NS server need 5 seconds to look up the DNS entry.

Your workaround to using only the single result of MX record isn't gonna work in postfix. Postfix will try to [resolve the A record of all domain](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/smtp/smtp_addr.c#L454) returned from **best** preference MX record. MX record of `in.mailjet.com` return 5 hosts with equal preferences. So postfix will lookup A record from five hosts.

To help speedup the DNS query, you can use NSCD and set `smtp_host_lookup` as `native` (as suggested by Andy). The other alternative is running local DNS caching like [powerdns](https://www.powerdns.com/) or [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/).